# Colourful 'dragon' (??!) response after git push

Tags: git, bitbucket

I just completed a git push to BitBucket, on a repo I use every day and my console received this colourful response back from remote...

(the remote being a BitBucket repo).

[image]

What on earth?!

Look a bit like a dragon....

Any idea what's going on?!

Thanks

Comment: This question is a duplicate.. Although, i answered it already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44720437/bitbucket-how-to-disable-strange-meaningless-coloured-guy/44720661#44720661)