# Bitbucket - how to disable strange meaningless coloured guy

Tags: git, bitbucket

I use bitbucket. Lately I began to see a big coloured guy in my console after every push. Since last week it appears more and more often.
It makes my log in the console longer and not convenient for work at all.

Is there any way to disable it at all?  I don't want to see it. I just want git.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: That's not a guy, that's the Atlassian logo: https://www.google.be/search?tbm=isch&q=bitbucket&tbs=imgo:1&gws_rd=cr&ei=jPxMWeKpHJLKwQLq8rmwBA#tbs=imgo:1&tbm=isch&q=atlassian+logo&imgrc=JRXnt9ppxQHcyM:

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem [it's a guy, too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(mythology)) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44649529/1366441), its to celebrate the

> anniversary of the declaration of same sex marriage as a legal right
>   in the US

You can disable it in your bitbucket account settings:

> Enable console messages: 
>   Disable to prevent Bitbucket from sending nonurgent console messages.

btw: its a duplicate question